# How to change verison of libstdc++.so.6?

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++

I am trying to change libstdc++.so.6 from 4.8.3 to 3.4.20.

Why am I doing this? Due to this error:

> File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /var/lang/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lgraph.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

Therefore, I assumed I would have to update the version. (I tried installing gcc-8.0.1 as well but either it didn't install correctly, simply did not work).

```
Architecture: 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Information:

$ bash-4.2# yum info gcc-c++

Installed Packages
Name        : gcc-c++
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 4.8.3
Release     : 3.20.amzn1
Size        : 0.0  
Repo        : installed
From repo   : amzn-main
Summary     : C++ support for GCC

I also ran this command:

bash-4.2# /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep stdc++
    libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
    libstdc++.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so
```

By the way, I am doing all of this on a docker container (If that matters). The program/package I am running was built on:

```
Information: 

Architecture: CEST 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

server:~$/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep stdc++
    libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
    libstdc++.so.6 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6
    libstdc++.so.5 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.5
    libstdc++.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so
    libstdc++.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so

server:~$gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.1.1 20180531
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is to build using an older GCC installation (e.g. GCC 4.8 like the machine where you run).  Another way is to simply copy the required libraries to the machine where you run, and put the path to them in the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Note that, at least quite often if not always, the libstdc++ is closely coupled with the version of the libc itself. So you need to copy more than just one library - and it will have to be built for the right version of OS too. I tried going down this sort of route a little while back, and couldn't really resolve the issues that ensued - I eventually got all the necessary parts copied, but it would seg-fault, most likely due to incompatibility between OS versions on the host and target systems.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by manually installing gcc-8.0.1 on my docker container and adding the correct path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.